# Volume of a tetrahedron given length of edges.

Tags: 3d, volume

I found this method to find the volume of a tetrahedron given the length of edges on Wikipedia

[image]

I found this Interesting, and was looking for a formal proof, but didn't find it anywhere.

Could someone please show how this is proven?

Comment: For completeness, you should include the method/formula in your question.

Comment: @Travis I found it too long to type, so I took a screenshot